# Could not find type '{My Namespace}.CodeActivity1' in assembly '{My Namespace}'

Tags: visual-studio-2013, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-workflow

I want to create a State Machine workflow in Visual Studio 2013 for using in SharePoint 2013.

These are my steps:

1- Create a SharePoint 2013 Empty Project.

2- Create a Code Activity and leave it's default name (CodeActivity1)

3- Create an Activity

4- Build the project.

5- Add CodeActivity1 from toolbox to Activity.

6- Build Again and get this error "Could not find type '{My Namespace}.CodeActivity1' in assembly '{My Namespace}'."

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve my problem.

Just move CodeActivty1 to another project. then reference to it from workflow project.

The issue was resolved.